# Rails 3 Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, routes

How can I link up my routes so that the spec will pass? I have read here http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/

### The spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

    describe ConversationMembersController do
      describe "routing" do
        it "recognizes and generates #index" do
          { :get => "/conversations/123/members" }.should route_to(:controller => "conversation_members", :action => "index", :conversation_id=>"123")
        end
      end
    end
```

### Failing spec

```
ConversationMembersController routing recognizes and generates #index
     Failure/Error: { :get => "/conversations/123/members" }.should route_to(:controller => "conversation_members", :action => "index", :conversation_id=>"123")
       The recognized options <{"action"=>"123", "id"=>"members", "controller"=>"conversations"}> did not match <{"conversation_id"=>"123",
        "action"=>"index",
        "controller"=>"conversation_members"}>, difference: <{"conversation_id"=>"123",
        "action"=>"index",
        "id"=>"members",
        "controller"=>"conversation_members"}>
```

### The routes

```
resources :conversations, :except => [:edit] do
    resources :conversation_members, :as => "members", :except => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
      collection do
        delete :leave
      end
    end
```

### The output of `rake routes | grep conversation_members`

```
52: leave_conversation_members DELETE /conversations/:conversation_id/conversation_members/leave(.:format)                                        {:action=>"leave", :controller=>"conversation_members"}
53: conversation_members GET    /conversations/:conversation_id/conversation_members(.:format)                                              {:action=>"index", :controller=>"conversation_members"}
54: POST   /conversations/:conversation_id/conversation_members(.:format)                                              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"conversation_members"}
55: new_conversation_member GET    /conversations/:conversation_id/conversation_members/new(.:format)                                          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"conversation_members"}
```

Comment: In addition to the error you posted, can you please include the actual spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this?

```
resources :conversations, :except => [:edit] do
  resources :members, :controller => "conversation_members", :except => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
    collection do
      delete :leave
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation it appears that the :as option just changes the named helpers...so the actual url is still

```
/conversations/xxx/conversation_members
```

but you can refer to the route as

```
conversation_members_path
```

check out this great guide to [routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: So I will have to use `match ...` here or could would `scope` be appropriate?

Comment: I suspect match is the thing to explore. scope seems to create more named helpers rather than changing URLs...we're now venturing into the fuzzy edges of my routing knowledge...